# Magento admin event after invoice save

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, adminhtml, paypal, invoice

I'm trying to add some functionaltiy after generating invoice by magento store owner for orders. I'm using the following code

```
<sales_order_invoice_save_after> 
    <observers>
        <sales_order_invoice_save_after_handler> 
            <type>model</type> 
            <class>invoice/observer</class>
            <method>saveinvoiceno</method>  
        </sales_order_invoice_save_after_handler>
    </observers>
</sales_order_invoice_save_after>
```

**Issue**

Above code is also working PayPal payment, but i want to execute it for admin only.
Any suggestion or help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please give some feedback? Did it answer your question?

Comment: issue  is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it should be for admin only, you have to put it inside `adminhtml` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        ...
    </modules>
    <global>
        ...
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_invoice_save_after> 
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_invoice_save_after_handler> 
                        <type>model</type> 
                        <class>invoice/observer</class>
                        <method>saveinvoiceno</method>  
                    </sales_order_invoice_save_after_handler>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```